# Converting an autopy bitmap to a Pillow image

Tags: python, screen-scraping, python-imaging-library, autopy

I'm developing a screen scraper in Python, using Autopy and Pillow.

Is it possible to convert a bitmap object to a Pillow image object?

My current solution is to save the bitmap object as an image file, and then use the path to create a Pillow image object. This approach is *really* slow because of harddrive I/O.

My current (very slow) solution:

```
from PIL import Image
import autopy

bitmap_object = autopy.bitmap.capture_screen()
bitmap_object.save('some/path.png') # VERY SLOW!
img = Image.open('some/path.png')
```

**Question:** Can the above functionality be achieved without saving the bitmap object to the harddrive?

Comment: Try using `ImageGrab` from `PIL` which does the same thing as `autopy.bitmap.capture_screen()`. Link [here](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageGrab.html).

Comment: That wont work, because Im using the autopy bitmap for many things, including searching for pixel patterns. I only need the PIL image for OCR.

Comment: size of the file generated by autopy?

Comment: @TarunLalwani ~3 MB

Comment: Can you try running it using PyPy instead of python and see if it helps? Not sure if PyPy support PIL and autopy but you can give it a shot

Comment: I'll give PyPy a look, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using `img = PIL.Image.fromArray(bitmap, mode=xx)`  This works for me with numpy arrays.  I see Autopy.bitmap has a `to_string()` method.  Not sure if that'll get you the raw data or not.

Comment: @bivouac0 the `to_string` method has no documentation on the format it produces. I'd love to help but I can't seem to install `autopy`, pip keeps returning errors.

Answer (score 2):

After looking through the source code it looks like there is not a way to directly access the raw bitmap. However, you can get an encoded copy.

First, get its encoded representation.

```
bitmap_encoded = bitmap_object.to_string()
```

This is encoded as "b", followed by the width, comma, height, comma, and a base64 encoding of zlib compressed raw bytes. Parse the encoded data:

```
import base64
import zlib

# b3840,1080,eNrsf...H1ooKAs=
#      ^    ^
first_comma = bitmap_encoded.find(',')
second_comma = bitmap_encoded.find(',', first_comma + 1)

# b3840,1080,eNrsf...H1ooKAs=
#  ^  ^
width = int(bitmap_encoded[1:first_comma])

# b3840,1080,eNrsf...H1ooKAs=
#       ^  ^
height = int(bitmap_encoded[first_comma+1:second_comma])

# b3840,1080,eNrsf...H1ooKAs=
#            ^
bitmap_bytes = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(bitmap_encoded[second_comma+1:]))
```

When I tested this on my machine, the red and blue channels were backwards so I'm assuming the bitmap from *autopy* is RGB encoded instead of the typical BGR encoding that BMP files use which is what PIL expects. Finally, load the image with PIL:

```
img = PIL.Image.frombytes('RGB', (width, height), bitmap_bytes, 'raw', 'BGR', 0, 1)
```

To load the image normally without swapping the red and blue channels, do:

```
img = PIL.Image.frombytes('RGB', (width, height), bitmap_bytes)
```

Comment: Did you happen to try iterating on the object directly? (ie... `for x in bitmap_object`)  I see there's a `Bitmap_iternext` that I thought might be usable to get a raw array, although I don't have this library installed here to mess with it.

Comment: @bivouac0 I did but it's not really useful. It appears to just yield the points. I.e., `iter(bitmap_object).next() == (1, 0)` and `list(bitmap_object) == [(1, 0), (2, 0), ..., (3838, 1079), (3839, 1079)]`.

Comment: Awesome solution, works perfectly, just what I was hoping for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like now this has a [solution from autopy](https://github.com/autopilot-rs/autopy/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-get-access-to-the-raw-buffer-in-an-autopy-bitmap):

```
import autopy
import PIL.Image

bmp = autopy.bitmap.capture_screen()
width, height = int(round(bmp.width * bmp.scale)), int(round(bmp.height * bmp.scale))
img = PIL.Image.frombytes('RGB', (width, height), bytes(bmp))
```