# Python: Convert bitmap to jpg on the fly

Tags: python-3.x, home-assistant

I am using autopy to take screenshots from my ubuntu desktop and publish to mqtt as a jpeg so I can view on home assistant via the mqtt camera entity. My solution works but I want to do the conversion on the fly without an intermediate file.

```
    screen=autopy.bitmap.capture_screen()
    screen.save("screenshot.jpeg")
    with open("screenshot.jpeg", 'rb') as f:
        filecontent = f.read()
    byteArr = bytearray(filecontent)
    client.publish(topic_screen, byteArr)
```

I would prefer to use autopy for the capture as I am using this to detect mouse movements in the same project.

Comment: Use a `BytesIO` https://stackoverflow.com/a/70275120/2836621

Comment: would be helpful to resize the image also to save bandwidth

Comment: why are you saving the image to disk? is that what you really want?

Comment: i dont need to save the image to disk - its because I couildnt find a solution to do it without an intermidiate file

Comment: @Mark Setchell Is there any way to avoid the PIL dependency? for isntance directing the sreen.save to an array as opposed to a file?

Comment: @SujitVasanth https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47797744/converting-an-autopy-bitmap-to-a-pillow-image you can look into this. Ideally you should avoid saving and reading from disk as it involves system calls and is much slower.